# JSON Parsing using Brightscript for ROKU app

Tags: roku, brightscript

I need to parse JSON received from API calls. Can anyone please suggest me any example link as I am not getting JSON parsing example at Roku blog.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431148/how-to-make-api-request-to-some-server-in-roku and also check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597380/difference-between-asyncgettostring-and-asyncpostfromstring

Comment: your issue is solved now?

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I am still working on my issue. But I am getting api response properly. I referred suggested links from you. I am new to Roku app development and sample code n tutorials are not available that much. Btw Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Roku docs,

Let's say you have an API response like this:

```
{
      "photos" : [
           {  
                 "title" : "View from the hotel",
                 "url" : "http://example.com/images/00012.jpg" 
           },
           { 
                 "title" : "Relaxing at the beach",
                 "url" : "http://example.com/images/00222.jpg" 
           },
           { 
                 "title" : "Flat tire",
                 "url" : "http://example.com/images/00314.jpg" 
           }
      ]
}
```

Then, to interact with the response is as follows:

```
searchRequest = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
searchRequest.SetURL("http://api.example.com/services/rest/getPhotos")
response = ParseJson(searchRequest.GetToString())
For Each photo In response.photos
    GetImage(photo.title, photo.url)
End For
```

You can see more details [here](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/language/global-utility-functions.md#parsejsonjsonstring-as-string-as-object)

Notice that you need to set some certificates to make requests [here](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/components/rourltransfer.md).

It's important to understand the whole functionality, however, there are some libs you can use to make request less painful. Usually, you end up creating your own wrapper.

I'm not the owner of this [repo](https://github.com/trystant/Roku/blob/master/SDK/examples/source/twitterOAuth/source/url.brs), I've have seen this NewHttp function on several projects.

In case you want to use that wrapper, you can do it as follows:

```
m.http = NewHttp(url,invalid,"GET")
m.http.AddHeader("X-Roku-Reserved-Dev-Id", "")
response = m.http.GetToStringWithTimeout(10)  

if m.http.GetResponseCode() <> 200 then
    print "Error while trying to get the response, ResponseCode:", m.http.GetResponseCode()
else 'the Response Code was 200(OK)'
   response = ParseJson(rsp)
end if
```

Hope this helps!